# How can I change a field to "mandatory" on the core registration page of Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

On an e-commerce site I've got two roles, *wholesaler* and *retailer*: I'm using `Auto-assign Role` to manage the registrations, with two different registration pages.

- *Retailers* register at
  `mysite.com/user/register`;
- *Wholesalers* register at `mysite.com/user/wholesale`

I'm also using [Ubercart](http://ubercart.org) and [Ubercart Addresses](http://drupal.org/project/uc_addresses) and I need the applicants to the wholesaler role to enter mandatorily the Company name: how can I set it?

CCK is not a solution, neither are other modules, because all I need is that field to be mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

function dag729_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_register' && $_GET['q']=='user/wholesale') {   
    $form[0]['company']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

That's it.

Actually the UID requirement couldn't be meet, because during the registration the user is Anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial from Lullabot that explains two ways of doing it: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6

In the module method, you'll want to set something like this:

```
$form['company-field-name']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

I don't know the actual name of the field in question (where I put company-field-name), so you will have to research that by printing $form to the screen or a file and reading through the output.

Additional information about creating a module:

I'm going to assume that you are doing the module over ride fro Drupal 6, which is listed under the heading of "Module hook_form_alter(): D6" in the link I posted above.

This information can be found on Drupal's website, here: http://drupal.org/node/231276

What you need to do is create a modules directory where ever your website's settings.php file is located (probably in sites/default). In the modules directory, create another directory that is the name of your module. I usually name modules like this zzzmods, or similarly. In that directory, create an info file of the same name (i.e.: zzzmods.info). In that file, add the following three keys with relevant values:

```
name = "Module name"
description = "Module description."
core = 6.x
```

Now, create a module file of the same name in that directory, i.e.: zzzmods.module. In that file is where you would place the relevant code, something like this:

```
function zzzmods_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    // You need to figure out what the id is of the form and put it here.
    // You can use the Form Inspect module to help with this and the field name below.
    case 'relevant_form_id_here':
      global $user;
      // Specify the role you're looking for here.
      if (in_array('Wholesalers', $user->roles)) {
        $form['relevant-field-name-here']['#required'] = TRUE;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

I haven't tested the above, so it might need tweaking.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problems that remain are: what file I'll have to modify and how to do it ONLY for a specified role?

Comment: also, the problem remained, since it needs to be required on a specific url only.